# relative path for links when using include php

Tags: php, include, href

I have two files, index.php in directory htdocs and MR.php in the subdirectory htdocs/Sub. Then I have a file menu.php in directory htdocs (same directory as index.php) that provides a navigation menu at the top of the two pages.

I include menu.php in index.php with

```
<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>
```

and I include menu.php in MR.php with

```
<?php include '../menu.php'; ?>
```

The file menu.php contains the hyperlink

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
```

But this link will not work when the page MR.php is displayed, because it directs to Sub/index.html instead of index.html.

In other words, the links in the included menu.php file are relative to the page that is displayed instead of the location of menu.php in my file system. How can I fix this so that the links in menu.php are always relative to the place where menu.php is?

I have spent a long time searching on this forum and elsewhere, and I understand that one solution would be to use absolute paths but then it would be a problem when I move the site to a different computer.

I have been trying

```
<a href="<?php echo $web_root; ?>index.php"> Home </a>
```

but it did not work, and in any case I do not understand how this would be different from using absolute paths. I would like to be able to upload the site to a remote server without having to adjust any links.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `<?php define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__); ?>` Then `<a href="<?php echo ROOTPATH.'/index.php'; ?>index.php"> Home </a>` Or if you're using a PHP version below 5.3: `define('ROOTPATH', dirname(__FILE__));`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and the hyperlink Home now points to the right place, but I get a "Page not found" error, both on my local computer (a Mac) and on a remote server. I think the problem (at least on my computer) is in how the localhost address is resolved, that I do not understand. The absolute path for the file index.php is /Users/myname/Sites/htdocs/index.php

Comment: The link correctly points to /Users/myname/Sites/htdocs/index.php but my computer will only display the page with localhost/~myname/htdocs/index.php . Same problem on the remote server.